# How To Select UIView That Received Touch Event

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm just getting into UIView touch events and I'm not sure how to get the UIView that actually received the touch.

I have a UIScrollView with multiple UIImageViews in it. Each UIImageView has a touch listener. I would like to get the UIImageView that receives the touch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think a "touch listener" is, but the way to do this, if you want to detect something like a tap on an image, is to give every image view a gesture recognizer and give each gesture recognizer an action target and handler. When a tap happens, the gesture recognizer passes itself to its action handler. In the action handler, examine the gesture recognizer's `view`.

Comment: Lots of further explanation and examples in my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html#_gesture_recognizers

Comment: Mucho gracias. I knew it was super simple but the examples I was looking at were overkill!